# Android Studio: Creating a Full Screen Button In The Media Controller For a VideoView

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview

I have been searching the internet for quite some time on how to create a full screen button in my media controller for my video. I have seen some websites showing how to do it, yet most of the methods I cannot understand as I am new to android studio. I have been able to add a media controller to my application, just not with a full screen button. So that when you click it in the media player, it goes from half the screen into full screen and then when in full screen, when you click the same button, it changes back. I know this requires a custom media controller, yet I have tried most of the ones I have seen online and they do not work. Please help

Here is my basketball shooting xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar_color"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/action_bar_color"
                android:elevation="4dp"> </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Video"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/md_divider"
                    android:layout_gravity="left">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/VideoAndTitle"
                        android:layout_margin="7dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/VideoHolder"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF"
                            android:layout_weight="50">

                            <VideoView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                                android:elevation="2dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/VideoTitle"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:id="@+id/video_title"
                                android:text="Basketball Shooting Tutorial"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_gravity="start"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Description"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:showDividers="none"
                    android:background="@color/md_divider">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:text="Description"
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:padding="5dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Small Text"
                            android:id="@+id/textView4"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:padding="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my BasketballShooting.java

```
package com.jehan.sportstutorials;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;



public class BasketballShooting extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
VideoView videoview;

String VideoURL = "https://ia801507.us.archive.org/13/items/basketball_shooting.3gp/basketball_shooting.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basketball_shooting);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    BasketballShooting.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("video");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Video);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Video");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("description");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Description);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Description");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    //VideoView
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    // Create a progressbar
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BasketballShooting.this);
    // Set progressbar title
    pDialog.setTitle("Basketball Shooting Tutorial");
    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                BasketballShooting.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_basketball_shooting, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_bar) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Since I am new to android, a simplified explanation would be very much appreciated.